# How hibernate session works

Tags: hibernate

I have some kind of trivial queries in Hibernate.

1. If I assume there are two instances running and each is using its own hibernate session. If one session inserts data into DB and the second session tries to retrieve the new data, will it be able to get that data?
2. I have set the primary key to be generated by a DB sequence.
   So I create an instance and call save() but do not commit the transaction. I am still able to get the ID of that instance. Is there a DB call happening at that moment or how does hibernate maintains its session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes, once the data is committed to the DB; this does depend on the [isolation level](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~aps/syllabi/2004_2005/issws/h03/hibernate.html#transaction) configured on the transaction
2. Yes, it will be something like `select nextval('MY_SEQUENCE');` this will be the id set to the entity; so, you have an id even if the transaction is not committed yet.

[This article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions) is worth a read.

Comment: The answer to point number 1 should also mention isolation levels, like read uncommitted. Even if transaction has not been commmitted, but if the isolation level is such that others are allowed to see intermediate changes, I think the changes might be visible.

Comment: Good point; I've added a link where this is described. By default however, the isolation level will be Read Committed which means that transaction A cannot read values that were not yet committed by transaction B.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys...the links are really helpful